# Tripping GFI circuit breakers

Tags: electrical

Have a brand new detached structure (guest house) with a sub panel fed from the main house service.  ALL 10 GFI breakers are tripping here a various times every day and by morning, ALL of the breakers are tripped every day.  The building is not occupied yet and some of the breakers are powering outlets (fridge, dishwasher, disposal) with no appliances yet and nothing even plugged into the outlets.  Any ideas what could be causing this??

Comment: Any signs of water getting into the panel?

Answer (score 1):

GFCI's trip when current is taking an unexpected path back to ground. As it is all or multiple of these outlets that are tripping randomly you likely have an issue with Neutral / Ground bonding in the wiring between your main breaker panel and the sub panel. It's also possible something is wrong in the way you wired each outlet leading to a bonding issue, or more general grounding issue.

This post is probably similar to your issue.

[Why would bridging Neutral and Ground trip a GFCI breaker?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/249855/why-would-bridging-neutral-and-ground-trip-a-gfci-breaker)

Answer (score -1):

GFCI circuit breakers have a periodic self-test feature.  This means a new, incorrectly installed breaker could trip itself on a regular basis.

If it helps make more sense to test under load, then plug in a vacuum cleaner and see if the circuit works or not.

If you're planning to fix this on your own, the first step is to carefully remove the panelboard cover and check or photograph the breaker connections.  Also look at the ground and neutral bars and try to confirm they are isolated from each other.